# many multiple conditional checks in single excel function

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet with four cells in which users enter either a y(es) or n(o), and based on all the possible results of those four entries I need to determine a value for another cell. So if the user entered "y" in all four cells then the value is 100; if "y" in any 3 of the cells and "n" in the other then the value is 75; two "y" and two "n" value is 50; and one "y" so three "n" and the value equals 25.

I am thinking of going this route:

```
=IF(AND(D2="Y",E2="Y",F2="Y",G2="Y")),100,IF(AND(D2="Y",E2="N",F2="Y",G2="Y")),75,IF(AND(D2="Y",E2="Y",F2="N",G2="Y")),75,IF(AND(D2="Y",E2="Y",F2="Y",G2="N")),75,C2)
```

but get errors. I am not an excel wiz by any means and wonder what the problem is as excel does offer much intuitive help other than the formula is in error.

Of course this formula only accounts for the conditions where value would equal either 100 or 75. Once that works then adding in the conditions for value = 50 and 25 should be easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically number of "y"s * 25?  Use this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(D2:G2,"Y")*25
```

I recommend having a look here for more info on COUNTIF: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34

Comment: I knew there was surely a more streamlined way to go about this. If the 25 represents minutes, how can I calculate and display the result in minutes? I tried `=COUNTIF(D2:G2,"Y")*(TIME(0,25,0))`, but that gives a value less than 1 in decimal.

Comment: The way you have it is fine, you'd just need to format the cell for a Time value instead of General.  The way Excel handles date and time is each whole number is 1 day, and the decimal is the percentage of the day that has passed.  For example, at 6:00 am, 25% of the day has passed, so the decimal portion would be 0.25.  If you format the cell as time, Excel will display the time value as desired.

Comment: Yes again. Thanks, all is working and looking as I'd hoped.